# Why does my NavController cannot find an ID that I already have?

Tags: java, android

Every time when I launch my app it crashes and Logcat says this:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity

So I think this is saying ID is not found, but here's my Java file and XML file corresponding to each other.
Java:

```java
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment);
```

XML:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.285"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

The Logcat says failed because the java file, ID does not reference a View inside this Activity. But I clearly typed the ID: nav_host_fragment.
I don't know what's wrong and when I'm inside Android Studio and it DID NOT report ANY error. Please help.

Comment: Are you calling `findNavController` after you call `setContentView()`? Can you show your activity's code?

Comment: It is before setContentView()

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`Navigation.findNavController` relies on `findViewById()`, which only works after you've called `setContentView()` - i.e., actually added your Views to your activity.

Comment: Whether you set the content view directly or via DataBinding, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 8):

Use the appropriate controller to avoid ID does not reference a View inside this Activity or fragment?

**if you are using Java**

In Activity use

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

In Fragment use

```
NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
// or
NavHostFragment.findNavController(view)
```

**if you are using kotlin**

In Activity use

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

In Fragment use

```
val navController = findNavController()
```

Answer (score 4):

I think we have to use it once the view is created. Tried putting the code in onPostCreate and it is working fine.

note: It was not working inside onCreateView

```
override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)

    val navController=findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across the problem I was having. I was trying to access a nested resource within the navigation.

Instead of

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_print)
```

Update to

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
navController.navigate(R.id.nav_print)
```